# Co-op difficulty when players are of different levels

Tags: dead-rising-3

I am in chapter 7 now, and on level 34, and a friend is buying the game today so we are planning on playing the entire campaign in co-op.

However, I have discovered that zombies that just roam the streets have upped their difficulty as my game progressed. As an example, police zombies that fired their handgun randomly in the start now carry shotguns and there are also SWAT-like zombies that have assault rifles.

I don't know if this change of difficulty happened because I leveled up or because I moved to different chapters.

What happens if I, with my level 34 player team up with my level 1 friend, who just started the game, will the difficulty ramp up likewise or will I just be a bit more powerful than him, but playing on his difficulty?

Comment: Exactly as @Flaunting has said, if your friend hosts the game and you join it the hardness shall be set to his or hers current level not yours.

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends who hosts the game.

If your friend does it will be a lower difficulty because the enemies ramp with both game completion (with each chapter) and level. so if he hosts it it will be more aimed for lower levels and you will be very overpowered.

If you host it your friend will die. lol

well maybe not but it will probably be way to difficult for him.